# Deal with NAs in conditional column

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, conditional-statements

I have a data frame such as df, and want to create columns to generate df2.

```
df <- data.frame(bind_cols(x = c('N', 'Y', 'N', 'Y', 'N'),
                   y = c(NA, 'N', 'Y', 'Y', 'N')))

df2 <- data.frame(bind_cols(x = c('N', 'Y', 'N', 'Y', 'N'),
                        y = c(NA, 'N', 'Y', 'Y', 'N'),
                        any = c('N', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'N'),
                        both = c('N', 'N', 'N', 'Y', 'N')))
```

The new column 'any' should = 'Y' if either one or the other or both of x and y == 'Y'. Both should = 'Y' if both x and y == 'Y'.
I have not figured out how to deal with the NA in the first row to make the any = 'Y.' My current strategy is below, but gives an NA in row 1, 'any' column, where I want to to = 'Y'. How do I alter the code to give a result of Y even when there is an NA value?

```
df2 <- df %>% 
  mutate(any = case_when(x =='Y'|y=='Y' ~'Y',
                         x != 'Y' & y != 'Y' ~ 'N'),
                both = ifelse(x=='Y'& y=='Y', 'Y', 'N'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `any` and `all` functions from base R with `na.rm = T`. They both act over vectors, so you need to add `rowwise` before the `mutate`s so you're treating each row's `x` and `y` values together as your vector, instead of all `x` values and all `y` values.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
    rowwise() %>%
    mutate(any = ifelse(any(x == "Y", y == "Y", na.rm = T), "Y", "N")) %>%
    mutate(both = ifelse(all(x == "Y", y == "Y", na.rm = T), "Y", "N"))
#> Source: local data frame [5 x 4]
#> Groups: <by row>
#> 
#> # A tibble: 5 x 4
#>   x     y     any   both 
#>   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#> 1 N     <NA>  N     N    
#> 2 Y     N     Y     N    
#> 3 N     Y     Y     N    
#> 4 Y     Y     Y     Y    
#> 5 N     N     N     N
```

Created on 2018-05-07 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Answer (score 0):

You can try `case_when` or `ifelse`. Use `%in%` instead of `==` to directly 
handle `NA`'s

```
df %>% 
  mutate(any=case_when(x %in% "Y" | y %in% "Y" ~ "Y", TRUE ~ "N"),
         both=ifelse(x %in% "Y" & y %in% "Y", "Y", "N"))
  x    y any both
1 N <NA>   N    N
2 Y    N   Y    N
3 N    Y   Y    N
4 Y    Y   Y    Y
5 N    N   N    N
```

No need for `rowwise`.

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain why the == and %in% behave differently?

Comment: @user42485 please check `?match`. %in% never returns NA makes it particularly useful in if conditions.